# How can I prevent the callback from loading at page load using Dash?

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly, plotly-dash

I currently have the following dashboard built using Dash:

```
from dash import Dash, dcc, html, Input, Output, State
from fredapi import Fred
import plotly.express as px

fred = Fred(api_key=API_KEY)
df = fred.get_series_all_releases('GDP')

app = Dash(__name__, suppress_callback_exceptions=True)


@app.callback(
    Output('chart-container', 'children'),
    Input('add-chart', 'n_clicks'),
    State('chart-container', 'children'))
def display_charts(n_clicks, children):
    new_chart = dcc.Graph(id='line-graph', figure=px.line(df, 'date', 'value'))
    children.append(new_chart)
    return children


app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Button("+ Add Chart", id="add-chart", n_clicks=0),
    html.Div(id='chart-container', children=[]),
    html.Div(id='chart-container-output')
])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

I have setup a button that allows for a new chart to be added upon clicking and that is working correctly. However, a graph is shown upon page load when I want the page to start empty. The way I understood the callback is that it only occurs when the user interacts with the component - but I now realize that to be wrong.

How can I adjust this so that no chart is loaded upon initial load of the page?

I thought about just clearing the children list after load but that seems to be a bad solution.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have you `df` so please tried this below code. I think you need to add option that if `n_clicks==0`, nothing shows:

```
@app.callback(
    Output('chart-container', 'children'),
    Input('add-chart', 'n_clicks'),
    State('chart-container', 'children'))
def display_charts(n_clicks, children):
    if n_clicks == 0:
        raise PreventUpdate 
    elif n_clicks > 0:         
        new_chart = dcc.Graph(id='line-graph', figure=px.line(df, 'date', 'value'))
        children.append(new_chart)
        return children
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add

```
prevent_initial_call=True
```

to your Input?  See [Dash Docs](https://dash.plotly.com/advanced-callbacks#prevent-callbacks-from-being-executed-on-initial-load) for details (search for prevent_initial_call)